# How can I fix this error "Trying to get property 'title' of non-object" in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

Background:
I installed a new Laravel version 8.49.2, and moved my app logic (controllers, routes, views, middlewares, models, custom configs) from (a legacy Laravel v5.8 project), Everything works well as expected so far.

But when I access a relationship attribute in blade I get the following error: `Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View: /Path/to/resources/views/users.blade.php)`

Blade:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<p> {{ $user->roles->title }} </p>
@endforeach
```

This

```
<p> {{ $user['roles']['title'] }} </p>
or
<p> {{ $user->roles['title'] }} </p>
```

Also gives the error `Trying to access array offset on value of type null`

The Controller:

```
$users = User::with(['roles'])->get();
return view('users', compact('users'));
```

User Model:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'levelId'); 
}
```

Role Model:

```
    public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'levelId');
}
```

When I die and dump `dd($user->roles->title)` I get the value `"Admin"`
But just echoing it like so `{{ $user->roles->title }}` gives the error.

***NOTE:***
When I change my PHP version to 7.3, this does not give an error. But in PHP 7.4.20 or 7.4.21 this error occurs. But I need PHP 7.4.*
Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: You have has many relationship, so you will get an array of Role object so you need to create foreach loop

Comment: I updated the code to show the error that occurs when accessed as an array.

    ```<p> {{ $user['roles']['title'] }} </p>
    or
    <p> {{ $user->roles['title'] }} </p>
```
Also gives the error `Trying to access array offset on value of type null`

Comment: one of the users doesn't have a role ... you have a loop so it could be any of them in that collection, you are only dumping the first one with the `dd`, use `dump` if you want to not kill the script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look like some users doesn't have role .So better check for null.When you `dd($user->roles->title)`  it only check for first user record not for all users.

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<p> {{ $user->roles->title??null }} </p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: All users have a role in my test database

Comment: @Cornel have you tried my sollution ? if still throws error  then dd($users->toArray()) post result in question

Comment: you were right. I should have double-checked